# Laravel log could not be opened (permission denied) on localhost (XAMPP)

Tags: laravel, apache, permissions, xampp, vhosts

I installed Xampp, downloaded Laravel into my Onedrive, and set up a vhost. But now, when I start the webserver, I get the following error:

> [Fri Feb 23 09:16:10.112460 2018] [php7:error] [pid 18040:tid 1968]
>   [client 127.0.0.1:63837] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file
>   "C:\Users\jordy\OneDrive\[....]\laravel\storage/logs/laravel.log"
>   could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied.

How is this possible? It has something to do with the file permissions. I checked many of the other topics here with the same problem, but I am using it on my local Windows 10 machine. What is the problem?

Comment: You need to grant your user all permissions to the storage/* folders

Comment: I already have that. I am a user with admin rights. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, you need to open the root directory of your laravel project and right click / properties of the storage folder and check permissions of it

Comment: I have full permissions.

Comment: Are you running windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10

Comment: You might have full permissions but laravel has not. If laravel was initilized as root. laravel isnt allowed to read the logs. type ``chmod 777 -R /logs`` in your root folder

Comment: You can't chmod on windows @Taacoo

Answer (score 0):

For windows grand permissions by command line:

```
icacls "c:\somelocation\of\path" /q /c /t /grant Users:F
```

`F` gives Full Access.

Comment: check it now, its for windows